# How to log the user out at timeout event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

The website has a forms authentication timeout and a session timeout. After the timer expires nothing happens, so it seems everything is working fine. But after pressing a button that requires a server response, the user gets logged out.

Instead the user should be logged out (or a login pop-up should be shown) directly when the timeout event happens.

Can this be resolved without javascript? 'Session_End' won't work because the website is hosted on multiple servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be reasonable to implement this without javascript.

It could be achieved with minimal javascript. By that, I mean most work could be on the server and the javascript only initiates the check but I can't see implementing this without some javascript.

Comment: I do want to be clear since some folks are rather literal on this site, that I'm sure there is some weird, "out of the box" way to do this without javascript. But the question becomes is it reasonable and worth while and my assertion is no -- a basic javascript implementation could solve this.